# How do I tighten an out-of-reach PVC pipe fitting?

Tags: plumbing, pipe, tools, pvc

A PVC pipe got pulled out of its fitting under my shower (don't ask!). It's been pushed back into position, but is out of reach by hand and not tight (causing a slow-drip). Above the pipe is a shower tray and below is a ceiling of our lounge.

**I'd like to tighten the fitting**, but would need to extend my arm length by about 1-2ft to do it without tools :)

I have thought about fudging together a tool to attempt this - perhaps a metal grip with a length of copper piping on each arm to give me that extra reach. However I'm not sure if the grips will end up ruining the PVC compression fitting or if I'll even get enough purchase.

Last resorts seem to be to remove the shower tray above or cut a hole in the ceiling below for access; the first is a pain, the second would be unsightly and I'd like to avoid either if possible.

**There must be a tool to give me that extra reach, does anyone have any ideas?**

Image below - you can see the white PVC fitting that needs tightening at the back with the drip tray underneath it.

Many thanks!

[image: PVC pipe]

Comment: That installation is improper I think.  AFAIK you're only supposed to use screw type fittings in spaces you can actually reach.  IN a closed space like under a shower it should be glued shut.  You'll have to open the ceiling under the shower.

Comment: Oh and "there must be a tool that..." is not binding upon reality.

Comment: There are [telescoping basin wrenches](https://www.homedepot.com/p/206830601) but you haven’t told us exactly how far this fitting is, or the size of the pipe (neither of which can be guessed accurately from the picture).  What country is this?

Comment: Thanks for comments so far, all. Installation being improper doesn't surprise me, there is much wrong with the building inherited from previous owner. I am in the UK, and the fitting surrounds a 50mm pipe (2"). It's about 40cm out of my reach, so a little over a foot. The basin wrench is a great idea, I just need a large jawed one - perhaps something like [this](https://www.amazon.co.uk/TEKTON-WRN92003-Telescoping-Capacity-10-Inch/dp/B01D4ZF034?th=1) will work?

Comment: @James looks like you found your tool!

Comment: @Tyson - possibly! Assuming that doesn't work, any opinion on covering the thing with some sanitary sealant / PVC pipe glue as a final alternative before the dreaded ceiling cut? It's a waste pipe, so not under (barely any) pressure.

Comment: You can never successfully glue a pvc joint from the outside it will still leak.

Comment: @Tyson is absolutely right.  To properly glue a pipe the glue must be inside the connection.  The glue actually causes the pvc to soften some, bonding with the glue, then reforming to form a connection that's actually stronger than the pvc itself.  You can't form that bond w/ glue on the outside.

Comment: Get a suitable plastic access panel and cut a hole to fit that panel. You can tighten the compression fitting and put the cover of the access panel in place. Later you can put in a proper glued in fitting. This* one might be too large, they come in various sizes. *https://www.supplyhouse.com/Viega-50718-14-x-18-Access-Panel-max-14-ports-6061000-p?gclid=CjwKCAjwhLHaBRAGEiwAHCgG3nd3892dTST16f9kNjOrj0OAvEK3X6EahVpKBalpxhJhDsqSdJ-zKBoCiogQAvD_BwE

Comment: What is the material of the ceiling, drywall (plaster board) or plaster? How hard would be it to cut an access port?

Answer (score 2):

put a wall access panel in the ceiling below the shower

http://loftsandladders.co.uk/plastic-loft-hatches.html

[image]